# protractor node-libcurl Failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: ssl, protractor, node-libcurl

I am trying to use node-libcurl module in my protractor project but I am getting the error :

> Failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

```
const  {curly} = require('node-libcurl')
const { data } = await curly.post('https://www.example.com', {
  postFields: JSON.stringify({"name":"rak"}),
  httpHeader: [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'
  ],
})
```

How to get rid of this error .

Answer (score 2):

From the [COMMON_ISSUES.md file on the project's repository](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/blob/develop/COMMON_ISSUES.md#error-ssl-peer-certificate-or-ssh-remote-key-was-not-ok):

> You need to set either [`CAINFO`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html) or [`CAPATH`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAPATH.html) options, or disable SSL
> verification with [`SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) (not recommended).
>
> The certificate file can be obtained in multiple ways:
>
> - Extracted directly from your system/browser
> - Downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html, which is based on the one
>   from Firefox
> - Creating a file with the contents of `tls.rootCertificates`, which was added with Node.js v12.3.0, example:
>
>   ```
>   const fs = require('fs')
>   const path = require('path')
>   const tls = require('tls')
>
>   const { curly } = require('node-libcurl')
>
>   // important steps
>   const certFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'cert.pem')
>   const tlsData = tls.rootCertificates.join('\n')
>   fs.writeFileSync(certFilePath, tlsData)
>
>   async function run() {
>     return curly.post('https://httpbin.org/anything', {
>       postFields: JSON.stringify({ a: 'b' }),
>       httpHeader: ['Content-type: application/json'],
>       caInfo: certFilePath,
>       verbose: true,
>     })
>   }
>
>   run()
>     .then(({ data, statusCode, headers }) =>
>       console.log(
>         require('util').inspect(
>           {
>             data: JSON.parse(data),
>             statusCode,
>             headers,
>           },
>           null,
>           4,
>         ),
>       ),
>     )
>     .catch((error) => console.error(`Something went wrong`, { error }))
>   ```